# How to change a variable in a option menu

Tags: android, optionmenu

First thing to say is that I'm a noob. I'm creating my first android app, after going through the tutorials. I want to create a little app that reads three specific rss feeds. I'm using a tutorial for building the rss part. But now I want to be able to change the rss feed in the option menu. So I want to change the variable rSSFEEDOFCHOICE when i clik a option in the options menu, but I just can't get it working and can't find anything online.. Here's my code:

```
    public class RSSReader extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener

{

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add("rss feed 1");
    menu.add("rss feed 2");
    Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu");
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        Log.i(tag,"rss feed 2");
        rSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "https://www.scouting.nl/publiek/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss";
        return true;
    case 1:
        Log.i(tag,"rss feed 2");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public final String tag = "RSSReader";
private RSSFeed feed = null;
private String rSSFEEDOFCHOICE;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    feed = getFeed(rSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try overriding [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, you're not setting the variable to a new rss feed.

Hope that helps.